# Kendo UI error when setting up Date Picker

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get Kendo Ui (Free Version working). I am trying to implement the date picker with the below code but alls I get is an empty input field. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="/Content/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
<body>
  <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.core.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.calendar.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.popup.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.datepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.data.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.list.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.combobox.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.dropdownlist.min.js></script>
  <script src="/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.multiselect.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.validator.min.js"></script>
  <input id="TimeSlot" name="TimeSlot" type="datetime" />

   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        $("#TimeSlot").kendoDatePicker();
        //var datepicker = $("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker");
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference all these javascript files in order for the DatePicker to work. You can use the [Kendo UI Custom Download tool](http://www.telerik.com/download/custom-download) to find out which javascript files you need to reference and to download a custom javascript file that contains everything you need:

```
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.calendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.data.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.list.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.combobox.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.dropdownlist.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.multiselect.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.validator.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE:**

Your text-box's id is "TimeSlot", but in your script you're referring to `#datepicker` which doesn't even exist. Change your script to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#TimeSlot").kendoDatePicker();
        //var datepicker = $("#TimeSlot").data("kendoDatePicker");
    });
</script>
```

By the way, you won't need `kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js` if you don't want to use Kendo's Html Helpers, which is not something that I would recommend if you are using asp.net MVC. With `kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js`, you wouldn't even need the script, you could just replace your text-box (input tag) with this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("TimeSlot"))
```

Comment: This has resolved the error messages from the console. How ever nothing is happening. No calendar icons are displayed near the Date Picker field. Any ideas why?

Comment: Please update your question with more information, for example, the screenshot of what you see on the page.

Comment: See edits regarding the test.html page that is not working in the original question for more details.

Comment: Where's your DatePicker? You just have some script on your page. Also, you're still missing `kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js`.

Comment: I can not see a Kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js file. Is it apart of Kendo UI Core?

Comment: It's part of the Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC. But, you didn't answer my other question. You don't even have a DatePicker on your page. How do you expect to see a DatePicker when you don't even have one?

Comment: Now I see what you're trying to do. Check my updated answer.